# Execute delete and update the respective rows in other table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle11g

I have following tables

```
CREATE TABLE A2SKU 
(
  SKUID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  SKUNAME VARCHAR2(20),
  SKUQTY NUMBER, 
  CONSTRAINT A2SKU_PK PRIMARY KEY (SKUID)
);


CREATE TABLE A2LOC 
(
  LOCID NUMBER NOT NULL, 
  LOCNAME VARCHAR2(20), 
  LOCQTY NUMBER, 
  MAXQTY NUMBER, 
  CONSTRAINT A2LOC_PK PRIMARY KEY (LOCID)
);



Create Table A2BOX ( 
boxId NUMBER Primary Key, 
skuId NUMBER, 
locId NUMBER, 
constraint FK_A2BOX_SKUID foreign key (skuid) references A2SKU, 
constraint FK_A2BOX_LOCID foreign key (locid) references A2LOC
);


CREATE SEQUENCE A2BOXSEQ;
```

I want to remove all boxes with a matching SKU from the A2Box table and Adjust the LocQty of the matching location in the A2Loc table of each box by 1

How I can do that using stored procedure.

I tried myself and came up with this

```
create or replace procedure A2DeleteSKU
(
pskuid IN number
)
AS
CURSOR row_cursor IS
      SELECT boxid,locid from A2BOX where skuid =  pskuid;
skuid_count Number;
skuid_check exception;

sku_rec row_cursor%rowtype;

Begin
select count(*) into skuid_count from A2SKU where skuid = pskuid;
if skuid_count <1 then
raise skuid_check;
End If;

 FOR sku_rec in row_cursor 

LOOP 
    delete from a2box where boxid = sku_rec.boxid;
    update A2LOC set locqty = locqty -1 where locid = sku_rec.locid;
 END LOOP;

   delete from A2SKU where skuid =pskuid;
   commit;
Exception
When skuid_check then
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20014, 'Delete Box failed. Boxid does not exist: '||TO_CHAR(pskuid));
When others then
raise;
End A2DeleteSku;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect opportunity to use the [RETURNING INTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354) clause, which when combined with a [BULK COLLECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21639/sqlexamples.htm#TTPLS337) can be extremely useful.

In order to use this you have to set up an array to hold the `locid` you are deleting. As it's possible to have multiple `locid`s for each `SKUID`, you may have to reduce the quantity by more than one per `locid`.

```
create or replace procedure remove_boxes ( PSKUID number ) is

   -- Set up an array to hold the deletes
   type t__locid is table of a2loc.locid%type index by binary_integer;
   t_locid t__locid;

begin

   -- Delete the rows and return the deleted locids
      delete from a2box
       where skuid = PSKUID
   returning locid
        bulk collect into t_locid
             ;

   for i in t_locid.first .. t_locid.last loop
      update a2loc
         set locqty = locqty - 1
       where locid = t_locid(i)
             ;
   end loop;

end remove_boxes;
/
```

It's possible you can change the `for .. loop` into a `forall` but I've never had to do this before and can't find confirmation that you can. If it's possible it would look like this:

```
forall i in t_locid.first .. t_locid.last
   update a2loc
      set locqty = locqty - 1
    where locid = t_locid(i)
          ;
```

As [Tom Kyte suggests](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteunindex.html) I would highly recommend indexing foreign keys; in this situation it would definitely be better.

Comment: No need to use row processing, two statements -- one update followed by one delete -- as in the other answers below will do it just fine, and increase performance too.

Comment: Of course @colin, I'm providing an alternative... the (currently) upvoted answer does do an unnecessary index range scan though... (assuming the columns are indexed).

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have edited with mine solution. Please check is that ok? Thanks

Comment: Also, @Colin'tHart now that I think about it you have to do row level processing as you can delete multiple locids for the same skuid so the other answers are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_boxes(pp_skuId NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
    UDPATE a2loc SET locqty = locqty - 1
      WHERE locid IN (SELECT locid FROM a2box
                        WHERE skuId = pp_skuId);
    DELETE FROM a2box
      WHERE skuId = pp_skuId;
END;
```

I am not sure what you mean with adjust locqty by 1. You have to modify the update command in the right way

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood the LOCQTY column on A2LOC represents the summary of boxes with the corresponding locid and you want it to be adjusted when boxes are removed. So, check the following code:

```
create or replace procedure adjustLoc(p_skuid number) is
begin

-- Adjusts the locqty value
update A2LOC loc
  set LOCQTY = LOCQTY  -1
 where exists(select 1 
                from A2BOX box
               where box.locid = loc.locid
                 and box.skuid = p_skuid);

-- Removes all sku matching boxes
Delete A2BOX 
where skuid = p_skuid;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure A2DeleteSKU
(
pskuid IN number
)
AS
CURSOR row_cursor IS
      SELECT boxid,locid from A2BOX where skuid =  pskuid;
skuid_count Number;
skuid_check exception;

sku_rec row_cursor%rowtype;

Begin
select count(*) into skuid_count from A2SKU where skuid = pskuid;
if skuid_count <1 then
raise skuid_check;
End If;

 FOR sku_rec in row_cursor 

LOOP 
    delete from a2box where boxid = sku_rec.boxid;
    update A2LOC set locqty = locqty -1 where locid = sku_rec.locid;
 END LOOP;

   delete from A2SKU where skuid =pskuid;
   commit;
Exception
When skuid_check then
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20014, 'Delete Box failed. Boxid does not exist: '||TO_CHAR(pskuid));
When others then
raise;
End A2DeleteSku;
```

Comment: Ugh, a `commit` inside a procedure. What if you call it form a larger transaction?

Comment: @DReispt, there's nothing intrinsically wrong with a commit inside a procedure. The thing is, as you say, you have to know where you're calling it from...